# Error Deploying DjangoCMS project to Apache - no such table: django_site

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, django-cms

I'm trying to deploy a DjangoCMS project onto an Ubuntu 16.04 Server running Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) with mod_wsgi. Running the development server works fine. When I try using Apache I get the following error.

```
OperationalError at /
no such table: django_site
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.9/
Django Version: 1.9.13
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: django_site
Exception Location: /home/jpb/.virtualenvs/gunjive/lib/python3.5/site-      packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 323
Python Executable:  /home/jpb/.virtualenvs/gunjive/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/var/www/django/gunjive',
 '/home/jpb/.virtualenvs/gunjive/lib/python35.zip',
 '/home/jpb/.virtualenvs/gunjive/lib/python3.5',
 '/home/jpb/.virtualenvs/gunjive/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/jpb/.virtualenvs/gunjive/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/jpb/.virtualenvs/gunjive/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 21 Nov 2017 18:55:28 -0800
```

I've tried deleting the DB and running makemigrations and migrate again to recreate the DB, but get the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually caused by the Apache user not having write access to both the SQLite database file and the directory it is in.

Comment: Thanks Graham - I did add myself to the www-data group, and the SQLite DB and directory have RW access: -rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data 237568 Nov 21 18:38 project.db